# How can I add a delimiter to the last value of my array in php using implode?

Tags: php, arrays, curl, implode

The problem at hand: I have one variable ZeroC that stores two arrays. I would like to send it to another PHP file using curl but only the first array sends. To get around this issue I tried imploding the variable into a string hoping to convert the two arrays into one long string, however, only the first array goes through. The implode function doesn't place a delimiter at the last item in the array (as seen in bold).

I can't concatenate the two arrays since they are stored in the same variable. If anyone has any ideas on how to solve this issue, thank you in advance.

```
        if($i==0){      
          $thisk= implode("%", $comments);
          print_r($thisk);
        }
```

Current output after using implode:

0%Correct def statement %0%Correct function Name %0%**Correct parameter 
0**%Correct def statement %0%Correct function Name %0%Correct parameter

Before imploding it (as an Array):

Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => Correct def statement [2] => 0 [3] => Correct function Name [4] => 0 )

Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => Correct def statement [2] => 0 [3] => Correct function Name [4] => 0 )

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: You could simply add the delimiter to the end after imploding, and for the final result strip off the delimiter again.

Example

```
$thisk = "";
for ($i = 0; i < 2; ++$i) {
    $thisk .= implode("%", $comments) . "%";
}
$thisk = rtrim($thisk, "%");
```

Or a more complete solution based on your original question:

```
<?php
$ZeroC = [
    ['0', 'Correct def statement', '0', 'Correct function Name', '0'],
    ['0', 'Correct def statement', '0', 'Correct function Name', '0'],
];

$result = '';
foreach ($ZeroC as $pieces) {
    $result .= implode('%', $pieces) . '%';
}
$result = rtrim($result, '%');
echo $result;
```

The output will be:

`0%Correct def statement%0%Correct function Name%0%0%Correct def statement%0%Correct function Name%0`

Comment: Thank you but it did not solve the issue. I've updated the code if you mind taking a look again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `%` at the end manually:

```
if ($i==0) {      
    $thisk = implode('%', $comments) . '%';
    print_r($thisk);
}
```

You may want to check if `$comments` is not empty to prevent a single `%` in the resulting string.

Comment: Thank you but even though it added the percent sign to the last value it also created another index pointing to null (which doesn't have a percent on it). And when I tried to explode it after imploding it still separated it into two arrays. Also, it is still only sending the first array to the back end.

Comment: So we'll have to see more of your code to get a better picture of the problem. A full working example.